# Package cmbright produces warnings, can't use with numbers

Tags: fonts

Here is my MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cmbright}

\begin{document}
$U$
\end{document}
```

It tells me `"Font shape 'TU/cmbr/m/n' undefined (Font) using 'TU/lmr/m/n' instead.`

Comment: cmbright doesn't support unicode engines.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't describe my question exactly. In fact, even the U (not the Chinese character) is also not supported. I have edited my question.

Comment: I didn't wrote "unicode characters" but "unicode engines". The package is not meant to be used with lualatex or xelatex. They want open type fonts, and not type1 fonts. You could force its use for numbers,  but then you would have to switch the font encoding all the time.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I know.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CM-unicode that supports CM Bright.

```
\documentclass{ctexart}

\setmainfont{cmunb}[
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*mr,
  ItalicFont=*mo,
  BoldFont=*sr,
  BoldItalicFont=*so,
]

\begin{document}

大$U$极限1a

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: However, this is different from what I want.